# Android Camera deprecated

Tags: android, camera, deprecated, android-camera2

I had an Android app which was able to take a simple photo showing a preview in a `SurfaceView` using the deprecated `hardware.Camera`.

**I did it this way:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.primeracapa);

    ajustes = getSharedPreferences("ajustes", MODE_PRIVATE);

    mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mySurfaceHolder = mySurfaceView.getHolder();
    mySurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.segundacapa,null);
    this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(capturar==true || !ajustes.getBoolean("longitudAuto", true))
            {
                myCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback, myJpeg);
            }
        }
    });
}

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
    }
};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera myCamera) {
        // Despues de hacer la foto que tiene que hacer
    }
};

PictureCallback myJpeg = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera myCamera) {
        if(data != null){

            File dir_image2 = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "foto");
            dir_image2.mkdirs();

            File tmpFile = new File(dir_image2,"TempGhost.jpg");

            try 
            {  
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (!dir_image2.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Directory not created");
            }
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    try{
        if(myPreviewRunning){
            myCamera.stopPreview();
            myPreviewRunning = false;
        }
        Camera.Parameters p = myCamera.getParameters();
        p.setJpegQuality(50);
        p.setPreviewSize(width,height);

        myCamera.setParameters(p);
        myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        myCamera.startPreview();
        myPreviewRunning = true;
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    myCamera.stopPreview();
    myPreviewRunning = false;
    myCamera.release();
    myCamera = null;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
    myCamera = Camera.open();
}
```

What I need to do now that Camera is deprecated is to do the same "simple" thing using camera2, and it's driving me crazy. Is it possible that camera2 is much more difficult to use.
I only need to see the preview of the camera on my `SurfaceView` and to be able to take a photo when a button is pressed and save it in a specific folder created by me.

Comment: "What I need to do now that Camera is deprecated is to do the same "simple" thing using camera2" -- why? `Camera` will continue working for years, for backwards compatibility. "Is it possible that camera2 is much more difficult to use" -- yes, it is much more difficult to use.

Comment: I thought it was best practice not to use deprecated elements.

Comment: It is a best practice to have a clear plan with respect to deprecated elements. In some cases, moving to something else is fairly easy and perhaps gives better results. In other cases, such as this one, moving to something else is a serious pain, and so you might postpone it. After all, in this case, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, you need the `Camera` code anyway, as `android.hardware.camera2` did not exist on earlier versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Was also playing around with the camera2 but in my case for video preview.
Perhaps you dont need the repeatingRequest but simple request. Hope this helps you a bit out to start with.

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        try {
          manager.openCamera(cameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {


                @Override
                public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    try {

                        CaptureRequest.Builder builder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_USE_SCENE_MODE);
                        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_PORTRAIT);

                        builder.addTarget(preview);
                        final CaptureRequest req = builder.build();

                        camera.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(preview), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                try {

                                    currentSession = session;
                                    session.setRepeatingRequest(req, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                    },new Handler());
                                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                //do something
                            }
                        },new Handler());
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    camera.close();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {

                }
            }, new Handler());
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```